# timestamp to date - is the result at UTC/GMT 0 coordinates?

Tags: google-app-engine, datetime

I have just converted some timestamps into date/time formats in Google Sheet with the formula:

```
=TIMESTAMP_CELL/86400+DATEVALUE("1/1/1970")
```

I get a readable date and time, such as `2014/06/12 12:00:00`.

Now I need to know if this result is at the UTC/GMT 0 (Greenwich) as I expect or in some local time...

Comment: If you're counting seconds since 01/01/1970 then it sounds like you're working with [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which is defined to be in UTC. However, without more information, the guess that we're working with unix times is just that, a guess. There are many timestamp schemes in this world and many can superficially resemble each other (i.e. there could equally be, somewhere, a system that counts the number of seconds since 01/01/1970 but in local time)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am pretty sure that the format is unix time!